# AWS CLI Mac show output only without opening a "vim"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Maybe it is for me but AWS cli on Mac it not outputting, it is like creating a new `vim` window when I have something like this. I am wondering is there a way to just show the output?

```
aws --cli-connect-timeout 6000 --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name test_queue
```

Cli version:

```
> aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.1 Python/3.9.0 Darwin/19.6.0 source/x86_64
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you are seeing the output of a pager.

There are a few ways to change this. I add the following to my `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

For details, see: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)